# Internet Explorer max-device-height media query with two monitors of different resolutions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

For an intranet site we have some users that use laptops with a resolution of 1366x768 with Internet Explorer 10 or 11

For this specific edge case, I've created a media query that uses `max-device-height` and hides certain elements to allow the page to flow better for them.

```
@media screen and (max-device-height: 768px) {
    .section img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If a user with such a laptop resolution connects an extended display that has a higher resolution, this media query still applies to a browser in that extended display in Internet Explorer.

This doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox, they correctly apply the expected media query on the extended display.

I'm purposefully avoiding `max-height` due to this causing a slightly jarring experience for desktop users internally if they tear off a tab and resize their browser.

Is there a method to avoid this in IE, or is that a JavaScript only solution?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue, and I made [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu9384hx/1/) that demonstrates things. IE reports the height of the monitor that is the "main display" in Windows, not the monitor that its window is on.

Comment: IE does, however, respond to the resolution in DPI of the monitor it's on. If your laptops have different DPIs than the external monitors, you can test for that. [Other fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yu9384hx/3/).

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll take a look at the DPI check